# Remove trailing zeros only from int numbers

Tags: mysql, phpquery

I have decimal column in db and trying to remove trailing zeros only from int numbers (100, 200, 300) with query in php. I tried with trim/cast functions but 10.50 turned 10.5.

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM `my_column`) FROM `mytable`
```

> 200.00
>
> 10.50
>
> 247.09

would display as

> 200
>
> 10.50
>
> 247.09

Comment: What is the datatype pf the column?

Comment: Datetype is: `DECIMAL(7,2)`

Comment: Does `TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM \`my_column\`)` work?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, work perfect for all numbers. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi, again. It doesn't work when use SUM() function .. I'm trying to get total sum from two nums and trim result but failed. E.G 2.50 + 3.20 = 5.7 must be 5.70

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case expression` to determine if a number is an integer using `ceil()` and if it is format with zero decimals, if not with 2 decimals.

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN ceil(n) = n THEN format(n, 0) ELSE format(n, 2) END
FROM (
      SELECT
            1234.5 AS n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            1234
    ) d
```

Comment: This works only for 1234. What if i have 10 records with int numbers?

Comment: You can also test `n % 1` (0 means no fractional part).